# Obj-C - best way to check if NSString passed to method equals previous invocation?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm new to Objective-C and I'm trying to determine if the NSString being passed to my method is the same as the NSString previously passed to the same method.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by `"is the same as"`. Do you mean "are the pointers identical?", or do you mean "are the strings equivalent in terms of their content"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to do this per instance of your class (and not globally):

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

- (void)myMethod:(NSString *)value;

@end

@interface MyClass ()

@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *value;

@end

@implementation MyClass

- (void)myMethod:(NSString *)value
{
    if ([self.value isEqualToString:value])
    {
        // Values are the same!
    }
    else
    {
        self.value = value;
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

Store the string as an instance variable of the class, each time the method is called, compare the instances and replace with the new parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Just to elaborate on what @Wain said:

Add Instance Variable:

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSString * lastString;
}
```

Then in your method:

```
- (void) methodWithString:(NSString *)string {
    if ([string isEqualToString:lastString]) {
        NSLog(@"Same String");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"New String");
        lastString = string;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A variation on the theme most answers are following: If you wish to do this *per instance* of your class then you can use an instance variable. However as this is something which is really specific to your method, you don't want to declare this variable in any interface and recent compilers help you with this by enabling instance variable declaration in the *implementation*. For example:

```
@implementation MyClass
{
   NSString *methodWithString_lastArgument_; // make it use clear
}

- (void) methodWithString:(NSString *)string
{
   if ([string isEqualToString:methodWithString_lastArgument_])
   {
      // same argument as last time
      ...
   }
   else
   {
      // different argument
      isEqualToString:methodWithString_lastArgument_ = string.copy; // save for next time
      ...
   }
}
```

(The above assumes ARC.)

The `string.copy` is shorthand for `[string copy]` and is there to handle *mutable* strings - if the method is passed an `NSMutableString` then this will copy its *value* as an (immutable) `NSString`. This protects the method from the mutable string changing value between calls.

If you want to do this on a *global* basis, rather than per instance, you can declare a `static` variable within your method and thus completely hide it from outside the method:

```
- (void) methodWithString:(NSString *)string
{
   static NSString *lastArgument = nil; // declare and init private variable

   if ([string isEqualToString:lastArgument])
   {
      // same argument as last time
      ...
   }
   else
   {
      // different argument
      isEqualToString:lastArgument = string.copy; // save for next time
      ...
   }
}
```

HTH